# Unable to launch jnlp(unable to load resource,class not found) in remote system but working in localhost

Tags: java, server, jnlp, red5

I'm working on Screen share using red5. I have a jnlp in my system in a red5 server. I am able to download and launch the jnlp and even share my screen to myself.

But when I try to access my jnlp file from my red5 server from another PC, I get 
"'Unable to load resource, screenshare.jar not found '". My red5 server is at 192.168.1.41:5080. The other PCs are able to access my server(all PCs are connected through LAN I think) at my IP(192.168.1.41:5080). After downloading and opening the jnlp, the other PCs get `screenshare.jar not found at 192.168.1.41:5080/screenshare`.

The jnlp application is not blocked! It says it can't find the `screenshare.jar`. My PC can find the jar and open the WebStart application.

Why cant the other PCs find it?

Comment: Are you using the same JDK on all the machines? Do you have any dependencies not installed on the server?

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) If it still does not work, post the JNLP content as an edit to the question.